# Get Telegram Topic ID (message_thread_id(topic)) without messages

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Good day,

I'm currently working on a project where I need to create a topic using a Telegram Bot and then post messages within that topic. My challenge is figuring out how to retrieve the topic ID (referred to as ***message_thread_id*** in the context of a topic) right after creating the topic. This ID is essential for my next step, which involves sending messages to the topic through the Bot. However, without knowing the topic ID in advance, I'm unable to proceed with posting messages. Could anyone guide me on how to obtain the topic ID immediately after its creation within my code, so I can use it for messaging purposes?

I'm looking to enhance a script that interacts with a Telegram group by implementing the following functionality: The script should first verify if a specific topic name already exists within the group. If the topic exists, the script will use a bot to send a message to this topic. However, if the topic does not exist, the script should be capable of creating the new topic and then proceed to send a message to it. This process aims to automate message posting to both existing and newly created topics within the group.

Best regards, Andrei

Comment: Your question is unclear, please limit the text to the actual problem, and remove any code you didn't write yourself.

Comment: Hello, @0stone0. Thank you for the suggestion. I made changes.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,
bots can use this method:
[channels.createForumTopic](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.createForumTopic)

The code is:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest, CreateForumTopicRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel, MessageActionTopicCreate
import asyncio

api_id = 
api_hash = 

async def fetch_channel_info(client, channel_username):
    channel = await client.get_entity(channel_username)
    full_channel = await client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel))
    # The channel object contains the id and access_hash
    return channel.id, channel.access_hash

async def create_forum_topic(client, channel_username, topic_name):
    channel_id, access_hash = await fetch_channel_info(client, channel_username)
    input_channel = InputChannel(channel_id, access_hash)
    result = await client(CreateForumTopicRequest(
        channel=input_channel,
        title=topic_name,
        # Add other parameters as needed
    ))
    created_topic_id = None
    created_topic_title = None

    # Iterate through the updates to find the UpdateNewChannelMessage with the forum topic creation action
    for update in result.updates:
        if hasattr(update, "message") and hasattr(update.message, "action") and isinstance(update.message.action,
                                                                                           MessageActionTopicCreate):
            created_topic_id = update.message.id
            created_topic_title = update.message.action.title
            break  # Assuming you only create one topic per request and can exit the loop once found
        
    # Check if we found the topic creation update and print the information
    if created_topic_id is not None and created_topic_title == topic_name:
        print(f"{topic_name}:{created_topic_id}")

    else:
        print(f"No forum topic with the name '{topic_name}' was created in the provided updates.")
    #print(f"Forum topic created: {result}")

async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('session1', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        await create_forum_topic(client, "ENTER_YOUR_GROUP_ID", 'Test-latest2')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(main())
```